# how do I display the total of the whole cart

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I display the total of the whole cart?

I want to display the Total price of the whole cart but instead, I get an item's total price when I increase the quantity on an item. I get a different value for every item in the cart. The logic for my total calculation is in the cart class in the totalPrice() Method

The cart Class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;
  Cart(this._cart);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState(this._cart);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  _CartState(this._cart);

  List<Dish> _cart;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
              tooltip: "Confirm Order",
              onPressed: () {
                if (_cart.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Order Confirmed",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
                if (_cart.isEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Cart Empty",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
              }),
          if (_cart.length > 0)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  _cart.length.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cart.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = _cart[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListTile(
                //Leading
                leading: Text(("Total: R") +
                    item.totalPrice().toString() +
                    "\n" +
                    item.category +
                    "\n" +
                    "R" +
                    item.price.toString()),

                //Title
                title: Text(item.brandName +
                    "\n" +
                    "(" +
                    item.counter.toString() +
                    ")"),
                //Subtitle
                subtitle: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.incrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),

                //Trailing
                trailing: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.decrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                isThreeLine: true,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The dish class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dish {
  final String category;
  final String brandName;
  final int price;
  int counter = 1;

  int sum;

  int totalPrice() {
    return sum = price * counter;
  }

  void decrementCounter() {
    counter--;
  }

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
  }

  Dish({this.category, this.brandName, this.price});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the total of the cart, it's possible to `fold` the list of `Dish()` to calculate the total:

```
_cart
 .fold<int>(0, (a, b) => a + b.totalPrice());
```

Follows a full example for the specified widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;
  Cart(this._cart);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState(this._cart);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  _CartState(this._cart);

  List<Dish> _cart;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
              tooltip: "Confirm Order",
              onPressed: () {
                if (_cart.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Order Confirmed",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
                if (_cart.isEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Cart Empty",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
              }),
          if (_cart.length > 0)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  _cart.length.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cart.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == _cart.length)
            return Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 4.0,
                child: Text("Cart Total: R" +
                   _cart
 .fold<int>(0, (a, b) => a + b.totalPrice())
 .toString()),
              ),
            );
          var item = _cart[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 2.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListTile(
                //Leading
                leading: Text(("Total: R") +
                    item.totalPrice().toString() +
                    "\n" +
                    item.category +
                    "\n" +
                    "R" +
                    item.price.toString()),

                //Title
                title: Text(item.brandName +
                    "\n" +
                    "(" +
                    item.counter.toString() +
                    ")"),
                //Subtitle
                subtitle: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.incrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),

                //Trailing
                trailing: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.decrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                isThreeLine: true,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where do I implement the _cart.reduce method? i get an error that says `The return type 'int' isn't a 'Dish', as required by the closure's context.`

Comment: You can find the full example in the answer's second snippet, more specifically it's from lines 71 to 83, in the `ListView.builder()`

Comment: I get an error that says The return type 'int' isn't a 'Dish', as required by the closure's context.

Comment: Do I Initialize the `a` and `b` variables? if Yes Where?

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer, please let me know if it solved the issue